# Uniqueness from Join in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have two tables:

Name_SSN and Phone_Address

Name_SSN contains
Joe xxx-xx-xxxx
Jim xxx-xx-xxxx
Bob xxx-xx-xxxx

Phone_Address
Joe 999-999-9990 Sunset Florida
Joe 999-999-9991 Sunset Florida
Joe 999-999-9992 Sunset Florida
Jim 999-999-9994 Sunny CA
Jim 999-999-9994 Sunny CA
Bob 999-999-9999 Raleigh VA

I want to do a join and get:
Joe xxx-xx-xxxx Sunset Florida
Jim xxx-xx-xxxx Sunny CA
Bob xxx-xx-xxxx Raleigh VA

I am new to pig and am clueless ...

Thanks for your assistance,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to perform an inner join in pig.  The follow code should help you:

**NameSSNAddr.pig**

```
--Load the two data files
namessn = LOAD 'Name_SSN.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (name:chararray, ssn:chararray);
phoneaddr = LOAD 'Phone_Address.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (name:chararray, phone:chararray, address:chararray);

--Perform the join of the two datasets on the "name" field
data_join = JOIN namessn BY name, phoneaddr BY name;

--The join combined all fields from both datasets.  
--We just want a few fields, so generate them specifically.
data = FOREACH data_join GENERATE namessn::name AS name, namessn::ssn AS ssn, phoneaddr::address AS address;

--You didn't say if you wanted the data distinct or not.
--If you want only one row per distinct user, use this alias.
data_distinct = DISTINCT data;

--Dump all of the aliases so you can see what's in them.
dump namessn;
dump phoneaddr;

dump data;
dump data_distinct;
```

**Output from `dump namessn`**

```
(Joe,xxx-xx-xxx1)
(Jim,xxx-xx-xxx2)
(Bob,xxx-xx-xxx3)
```

**Output from `dump phoneaddr`**

```
(Joe,999-999-9990,Sunset Florida)
(Joe,999-999-9991,Sunset Florida)
(Joe,999-999-9992,Sunset Florida)
(Jim,999-999-9994,Sunny CA)
(Jim,999-999-9994,Sunny CA)
(Bob,999-999-9999,Raleigh VA)
```

**Output from `dump data`**

```
(Bob,xxx-xx-xxx3,Raleigh VA)
(Jim,xxx-xx-xxx2,Sunny CA)
(Jim,xxx-xx-xxx2,Sunny CA)
(Joe,xxx-xx-xxx1,Sunset Florida)
(Joe,xxx-xx-xxx1,Sunset Florida)
(Joe,xxx-xx-xxx1,Sunset Florida)
```

**Output from `dump data_distinct`**

```
(Bob,xxx-xx-xxx3,Raleigh VA)
(Jim,xxx-xx-xxx2,Sunny CA)
(Joe,xxx-xx-xxx1,Sunset Florida)
```